# Database insertion taking too much time- android sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlite

I am trying to insert around 2800 records into the sqlite database, it is taking 150 sec, which is way too much! Could anyone please tell how to optimize this insertion.

```
    public void createVariantEntry(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> str) {
        InsertHelper ih = new InsertHelper(Database, VARIANT_TABLE_NAME);
        final int varid = ih.getColumnIndex(VARIANT_ID);
        final int varmakeid = ih.getColumnIndex(VARIANT_MAKE_ID);
        final int varmodid = ih.getColumnIndex(VARIANT_MODEL_ID);
        final int varname = ih.getColumnIndex(VARIANT_NAME);
        final int varposteddate = ih.getColumnIndex(VARIANT_POSTED_DATE);               
        for(int i=0;i<1253;i++)
        {           
            ih.prepareForInsert();
            ih.bind(varid, str.get(i).get(0));
            ih.bind(varmakeid, str.get(i).get(1));
            ih.bind(varmodid, str.get(i).get(2));
            ih.bind(varname, str.get(i).get(3));
            ih.bind(varposteddate, str.get(i).get(4));
            ih.execute();
        }                       
        for(int i=1255;i<str.size();i++)
        {               
            ih.prepareForInsert();
            ih.bind(varid, str.get(i).get(0));
            ih.bind(varmakeid, str.get(i).get(1));
            ih.bind(varmodid, str.get(i).get(2));
            ih.bind(varname, str.get(i).get(3));
            ih.bind(varposteddate, str.get(i).get(4));
            ih.execute();
        }           
        ih.close(); 
    }
```

Comment: I had actually left a comment on your previous question related to this, I believe you can use some StringBuilder to compose a complete String to trigger less insert process.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to do a string builder using inserthelper

Comment: its not about inserthelper, it has to be done using rawQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a great boost in performance will be gained when using transactions.

```
try {
    SQLiteDatabase db = MySQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabse();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    db.beginTransaction();
    while ( more_data_to_insert ) {
        // put the data in 'values'
        values.put("col_1", data_1);
        values.put("col_2", data_2);
        // ...
        values.put("col_n", data_n);

        // Insert the row into the database.
        db.insert("table_name", null, values);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch ( SQLiteException e ) {
    // handle your sqlite errors
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

and don't use `InsertHelper`. its deprecated now.

Comment: Hello i am using inserthelper but when i run it on devices having api levels below 11 i get a java.lang.verifyerror is that the reason why ? Because i am using a deprecated method ??

Comment: @DharaShah I can't really help u without details. so, please open a new question and let me know. i'd be happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some general tips that might help you:

- You can bulkInsert or applyBatch using ContentProviders to do a bunch of operations in one go:
  [How to use bulkInsert() function in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730908/how-to-use-bulkinsert-function-in-android)
- You can use transactions to speed things up as well:
  [Android Database Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147440/android-database-transaction)
- In some cases DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper has been known to provide faster inserts than the normal sqlite insert:
  http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/

After this, You'll have to do some benchmarking and optimize for your specific situation analyzing performance vs data integrity tradeoffs etc. Good luck.