# Parse JSON on the flight Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am using google GSON API to parse a JSON file for my Android project but I have an issue of performance.

Here is the source code I use for parsing the JSON with google GSON API :

```
public void loadJsonInDb(String path){
    InputStream isJson = context.getAssets().open(path);
    if (isJson != null) {
        int sizeJson = isJson.available();
        byte[] bufferJson = new byte[sizeJson];
        isJson.read(bufferJson);
        isJson.close();
        String jsonStr = new String(bufferJson, "UTF-8");

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject object = parser.parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray array = object.getAsJsonArray("datas");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        for(JsonElement jsonElement : array){
            MyEntity entity = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, MyEntity.class);
            // Do insert into Db stuffs
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that after parsing I have to go through the JsonArray with a for loop and perform the desired action (which is an insertion in SQLite DB with ORMLite of each element in the array), I would like to know if it is possible to perform insertion on the flight during the parsing, instead of waiting for the the array to be computed. I have seen in documentation that maybe [JsonStreamParser](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/JsonStreamParser.html) can do the job but I am not how to use it.

Comment: Probably database insertion is a bottle neck. Do you use content provider or direct insert? Do you use beginTransaction() endTRansaction()?

Comment: Indead DB insertion is one of the bottleneck, actually I measured processing time. For JSON parsing : 17 sec, for DB insertion : 50 sec. That is why I would like to insert data in DB on the flight during the parsing, it would be a kind of parallel processing (parsing + DB insertion). I don't use beginTransaction or endTRansaction, does it improve performances?

Comment: I had similar issue. Json array of about 1000 records. If use content provider insert time ~ 1 minute. If direct access to db (without content provider) and insert in single transaction takes ~ 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few notes regarding the use of Gson and other stuff.

- You should close I/O resources in `finally` blocks to ensure you don't have resource leaks (`available` and `read` may throw an exception that prevents the resource from being `close`d). (Also I'm not sure if using `available` is a good idea here.)
- You just don't have to use `String`s in this case. Strings are generally a performance/memory killer for such a scenario (much depends on their result sizes) since strings are accumulated into memory, thus you lose your on-fly idea having it's all collected into memory first. In worst cases, it can finish up your application with `OutOfMemoryError`.
- You can read input streams with a specified encoding, so no string-buffering is necessary.
- `JsonParser` is designed to return JSON trees: `JsonElement` contains the *whole* JSON tree in memory. Sounds similar to the strings case above, right? Another performance penalty here.
- Creating `Gson` instances may be somewhat expensive (depending on how to compare, of course), and you can instantiated it once: it's thread safe.
- `JsonStreamParser` is not an option too, because each `next()` will produce another JSON tree branch in memory (again, depends on how big are your JSON documents and its `$.datas` array and its elements).
- `Gson.fromJson` uses lookup to find the best type adapter, and you ask a `Gson` instance for a type adapter once, then not wasting time for lookups anymore. Type adapters are usually perfectly thread-safe too, thus can be cached.

Summarizing the above up, you could implement it as follows:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
private static final TypeAdapter<MyEntity> myEntityTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(MyEntity.class);
```

```java
private static void loadJsonInDb(final String path)
        throws IOException {
    // Java 7 language features can be easily converted to Java 6 try/finally
    // Note the way how you can decorate (wrap) everything: an input stream (byte streams) to a reader (character streams, UTF-8 here) to a JSON reader (more high-level character reader)
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(path), "UTF-8")) ) {
        // Ensure that we're about to open the root object
        jsonReader.beginObject();
        // And iterate each object property
        while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
            // And check it's name
            final String name = jsonReader.nextName();
            // Another Java 7 language feature
            switch ( name ) {
            // Is it datas?
            case "datas":
                // The consume it's opening array token
                jsonReader.beginArray();
                // And iterate each array element
                while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
                    // Read the current value as an MyEntity instance
                    final MyEntity myEntity = myEntityTypeAdapter.read(jsonReader);
                    // Now do what you want here
                }
                // "Close" the array
                jsonReader.endArray();
                break;
            default:
                // If it's something other than "datas" -- just skip the entire value -- Gson will do it efficiently (I hope, not sure)
                jsonReader.skipValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        // "Close" the object
        jsonReader.endObject();
    }
}
```

Simply speaking, you just have to write a parser to consume each token. Now, having the following JSON document:

```
{
    "object": {
    },
    "number": 2,
    "array": [
    ],
    "datas": [
        {
            "k": "v1"
        },
        {
            "k": "v2"
        },
        {
            "k": "v3"
        }
    ]
}
```

the parser above would extract `$.datas.*` only consuming as less resources as possible. Substituting `// Now do what you want here` with `System.out.println(myEntity.k);` would produce:

> v1
>   v2
>   v3

assuming that `MyEntity` is `final class MyEntity{final String k=null;}`. Note that you can process infinite JSON documents using this approach too.

Comment: Thanx for this update, I am going to try it. However can you please tell me to what corresponds myEntityTypeAdapter?

Comment: @Mouss Sorry, I forgot to attach it. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions here:

1. Deserealize entire collection in 3 lines:

   ```
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyEntity>>(){}.getType();
       List<MyEntity> listOf = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, listType);
   ```
2. When you got whole list of the entities use [`bulkInsert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#bulkInsert(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues[])) with single transaction. [There you can get the idea how do use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730908/how-to-use-bulkinsert-function-in-android)

P.S.
To use `bulkInsert` you have to create list of `ContentValues` from your Entities.